# Jquery - Make a link clickable in a div which appears/disappears when clicked

Tags: jquery

I need a div to appear and disappear when clicked. I managed to do it with Jquery.

Inside this div, I would like a link to be clickable too. The issue is that Jquery intercepts the click on the div before the link in itself.

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks a lot

```js
$(document).on('click', '.warningmessagenew', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(event);
  console.log("starting");
  var shorttextdiv = $(this).children(".shorttext")[0];
  var longtextdiv = $(this).children(".longtext")[0];
  console.log(shorttextdiv);
  if ($(shorttextdiv).css('display') === 'none') {
    $(shorttextdiv).show();
    $(longtextdiv).hide();
  } else {
    $(shorttextdiv).hide();
    $(longtextdiv).show();
  }
});
```

```css
        .warningmessagenew {
            max-width: 700px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .shorttext {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #bbcadf;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .longtext {
            display: none;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            line-height: 1.2em;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .longtextdesc {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <body>
    <div class="warningmessagenew d-flex">
      <div class="shorttext">(Aide)</div>
      <div class="longtext">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        </p>
        <p>
          cf <a href="/risk/" id="covidarticles" class="exceptionlink" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</a>
          consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below snippet.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.shorttext', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(event);
  var shorttextdiv = $(this)[0];
  var longtextdiv = $(this).next(".longtext")[0];
  if ($(longtextdiv).css('display') === 'none') {
    $(longtextdiv).show();
  } else {
    $(longtextdiv).hide();
  }
});
```

```css
.warningmessagenew {
            max-width: 700px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        .shorttext {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            color: #bbcadf;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-bottom: 30px;
        }

        .longtext {
            display: none;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            border-style: solid;
            border-radius: 5px;
            padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
            margin-bottom: 25px;
            line-height: 1.2em;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .longtextdesc {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <body>
    <div class="warningmessagenew d-flex">
      <div class="shorttext">(Aide)</div>
      <div class="longtext">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        </p>
        <p>
          cf <a href="/risk/" id="covidarticles" class="exceptionlink" target="_blank">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</a>
          consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leoLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut elit tellus, luctus nec ullamcorper mattis, pulvinar dapibus leo
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is also [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0j8wcqn/)

Comment: Thanks Bhautik. I see you let the "aide" link visible. I understand there is no way to have both the div and the link inside the div clickable ?

Comment: Yes, it's clickable. check I added jsfiddle link.

Comment: thanks Bhautik. The link is clickable but the div is not clickable anymore. What I would like to achieve is to have the "aide" text and the div switching when clicked

Comment: What you ask originally I already give you answer. this is now a different question. please ask as a separate question. also when you click on "aide" the div is switching.